# Exporting powershell output into sql server database

Tags: powershell

I have a function that am working on, I need the function to be able to write the results into a SQL database. Inside this function, I called another function named: Get-svnLogData, this function pulls information that has 4 columns.
Iam very knew to powershell coding and I desperately need help.

```
Function SQL-BulkInsert{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        #The name of the instance, if there is one
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$false,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false, 
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
                   Position=1)] 
        [string]$SQLInstance = "InstanceName",
        [string]$DatabaseName = "DBName",
        [string] $tableName = "dbo.CheckiList"

    )

     $Query="USE DBName
             IF  OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CheckiList]', N'U') IS NOT NULL
             DROP TABLE dbo.CheckinList

             CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CheckinList] (
             [Author]  varchar(200) NULL,
             [Revision] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
             [Msg] [varchar](100) NULL,
             [Path] [varchar] (250) NULL)" 




    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "InstanceName" -Database "DBNmae" -Query $Query


    $connection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
    $connectiomn.Open()
    $DataTable = Get-SvnLogData | Format-Table -AutoSize
    $bc = new-object ("System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $connection 
    $bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.CheckiList"
    $bc.WriteToServer($datatable)

    Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -SchemaName dbo -TableName dbo.CheckinList -InputData $DataTable




  }
```

I am getting this error: 'Write-SqlTableData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included

Please help me with either fixing my code or showing me another method. Its been 7 days trying to fix this problem but cant figure out how to insert data into SQL Database

Comment: Have you imported the module SQLServer?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Yes I tried that but I went into countless errors, see below:

'Write-SqlTableData' command was found in the module 'SqlServer', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SqlServer'.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin If I then run the: 'Import-Module SqlServer' as per above error, then i get another error, see below: 


Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultKeyPropertySet is 
already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present.

Comment: In addition to the above, this how am doing it:
Install-Module SqlServer -Scope Currentuser

Comment: Try it all again from a fresh PowerShell session.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks Jeff, you saved my life...It worked

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is telling you that the command does not exist. There is a variety of reasons for this. For one it simply could be a typo or similar. In this case, [as this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4627/new-powershell-cmdlets-to-read-and-write-sql-server-tables/) article would indicate, it's an official cmdlet that exist. So if it's not available it's likely that you didn't load the corresponding module.

In order to load a module you would use [`Import-Module`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module). To see which modules are available you can use [`Get-Module -ListAvailable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module).

If there is no SQL module available you might have to manually supply the correct path or check your installation.

If the import of a module was successful you can use [`Get-Command`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to check which commands have become available. The parameter `Module` is especially useful in this case.